# React table sort and search

Tags: reactjs

i have data like

```
const data =[
{
name:'gacvuc',
pot1[
{
density:1
}
]
pot2[
{
density:2
}
]
}
.....
]
```

now i made a toggle in that do we wanna see pot1 density or pot2 density
and made a table with that like this

```
<tablebody>
data.map(a,in)=>{
const show= toggleChoice === 0 ? a.pot1 : a.pot2;
}
return(
<tablecell>{a.name}</tablecell>
<tablecell>{show.density}</tablecell>
</tablebody>
);
```

now what i wanna do is i wanna sort by density in ascending or descending or search by it's name can anyone show me how to do that

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommend taking a look at the format of your data and looking for mistakes.

To sort your data, you can simply use the built-in sort method and pass in a function that gives instructions on how to sort two different objects in your data.

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
  // you can define this based on your toggle variable
  const pot = "pot1"; 
  
  // densities of both object
  const aDensity = a[pot][0].density;
  const bDensity = b[pot][0].density;
  
  // compare them and then return -1, 0, or 1 accordingly
  if (aDensity == bDensity) { // if they are equal, return 0
    return 0;
  }
  else if(aDensity > bDensity) { // > return 1
    return 1;
  }
  else { // < return -1
    return -1;
  }
})
```

In this snippet, you get the densities of two arbitrary objects, a and b, and then return -1, 0, or 1 depending on the values of the density. In this example. I sorted them in ascending order, but if you want descending, you could swap the 1 for -1 and vice versa in the code.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. This will sort the entire set of data, and therefore the table too. Am I missing something?

Comment: can you show me how this will work i want a button that will sort it ascending or descending order

Comment: I can show you, I'll need to know a bit more about what you're using though. Are you using react hooks in this project with functional components, or class-based react components with the normal react life-cycle methods?

Comment: yes i am using react hooks in this project

Comment: I think the best option here is to have two buttons that call the sorting method and depending on which button is clicked, it changes the return value from the custom comparator function I wrote above.